# Object change in C#

Tags: c#, oop, object

When I write this code I see an unexpected situation how can I solve this?

```
KurumReferans tempReferans = new KurumReferans();
tempReferans = kRef; 

if (kurumDetaylari.IsTakipMekanizmasiKullaniyor == true)
{
    KurumReferans kRefIstakip = new KurumReferans();
    kRefIstakip = kRef;
    kRefIstakip.Referans = "SORUMLU";
    kRefIstakip.Yontem = "SORUMLU:";
    kRefIstakip.Tipi = Tipi.Zorunlu;
    kRefIstakip.Parent = kurum;
    PostAddEdit(db.KurumReferans, kRefIstakip, cmd, "", "", "", "");
}
```

Firstly I assign,

```
tempReferans = kRef;
```

After when I assign `kref` to other object,

```
KurumReferans kRefIstakip = new KurumReferans();
kRefIstakip = kRef;
kRefIstakip.Referans = "SORUMLU";
```

`tempReferans` object's values change but I want to old values.

Comment: You need a deep copy, but you are doing reference assignment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your object is getting changed, because when you assign an object, it just assigns the address to it and both variable uses same memory space or object. To overcome this, you have to make a deep copy of the object and assign.

```
public static T DeepClone<T>(T obj)
{
 using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
 {
   var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
   formatter.Serialize(ms, obj);
   ms.Position = 0;

   return (T) formatter.Deserialize(ms);
 }
}
```

EDIT: You have mark that class with attribute [Serializable]

Comment: What happens if the object is not serializable?

Comment: You may use structures for this

Comment: Hi,I am using EF and I define class serializable but I am getting error Type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Kurum_BCDC2ACA1F84F93F1878F4DF523F0D5F5AEAE798E3E7DAD7F29BC65395A8AC41' in Assembly 'EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-EDocSis, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.     [Table("KurumReferanslari")]
    [Serializable]
    public partial class KurumReferans : IEntity
    {

Comment: try without serilizable in the case of EF

Comment: add a partial class and try add serializable [Serializable] partial class KurumReferans

Comment: @SriramSakthivel  He is not able to edit and do the changes in EF files, so asked to create partial class for the EF Class and add Serializable attribute

Answer (score 0):

In the line:

```
kRefIstakip = kRef;
```

the object `kRef` is also referenced by `kRefIstakip`. Because you are assigning `kRef` instance to `kRefIstakip`, not copying `kRef` to `kRefIstakip`.

In **Reference Type** objects, the code:

```
obj1 = obj2;
```

doesn't copy the values of `obj2` to `obj1`, but it copies `obj2` reference to `obj1`. And then both can access same memory location.